# ffmpeg with shell: oncat listed movies

Tags: shell, ffmpeg

I'm new to shell script, trying to concat listed movies in a folder like:

```
filename="list.txt"
cat ${filename} | while read line;
do
    ffmpeg -y -i sum.mov -i $line -filter_complex concat tmp.mov
    cp tmp.mov sum.mov
done
```

However, this loop runs only one time.
What is the best practice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:

```
#list.txt
file 'movie1.mov'
file 'movie2.mov'
file 'movie3.mov'
```

Don't need to write a shell script. Just

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -c copy output.mov
```